# Is there a way to programmatically return or release a connection to the pool?

Tags: postgresql, rust

I am using deadpool-postgres for a connection pool. Is there a way to programmatically return or release a connection to the pool?

Comment: connection are probably releases when droping the connection object itself.

Comment: if you need that you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs of `deadpool::managed::Object`](https://docs.rs/deadpool/0.8.2/deadpool/managed/struct.Object.html):

> Use this object just as if it was of type `T` and upon leaving scope **the `drop` function will take care of returning it to the pool**.

You can explicitly call `drop()` if you want to be explicit about it, otherwise just let the handle go out of scope.